# Give an example of a set with two binary operations, addition and multiplication, in which we have left distributivity but not right distributivity

Tags: binary-operations

Give an example of a set with two binary operations, addition and multiplication, in which the left distributive law holds but the right distributive law does not hold.  I.e.: $$a(b+c)=ab+ac\text{, but }(b+c)a=ba+ca.$$ If this is not possible, then  prove that one implies the other.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication of ordinal numbers is only left-distributive, not right-distributive, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property), and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951013/prove-that-ordinal-multiplication-is-left-distributive). A further discussion is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242291/curious-facts-about-ordinal-numbers).