# When would right distributive law hold?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm reading "Naive Lie Algebra" by John Stillwell, during introducing quaternion he mentioned:

> The quaternion sum operation has the same basic properties as addition
> for numbers, namely
> $$q_1 + q_2 = q_2 + q_1 ,\text{(commutative law)}$$
> $$q_1 + (q_2 + q_3 ) = (q_1 + q_2 ) + q_3 ,\text{(associative
>  law)}$$
> $$q + (−q) = \mathbf{0} \text{, where } \mathbf{0} \text{ is the zero matrix, (inverse
>  law)}$$
> $$q + \mathbf{0} = q.\text{(identity law)}$$ The quaternion product
> operation does not have all the properties of multiplication of
> numbers — in general, the commutative property $q_1 q_2 = q_2 q_1$
> fails — but well-known properties of the matrix product imply the fol-
> lowing properties of the quaternion product:
> $$q_1 (q_2 q_3 ) = (q_1 q_2 )q_3 ,\text{(associative law)}$$
> $$qq^{-1} = \mathbf{1}, \text{for } q \ne \mathbf{0} \text{, (inverse law)}$$
> $$q\mathbf{1} = q, \text{(identity law)}$$
> $$q_1 (q_2 + q_3 ) = q_1 q_2 + q_1 q_3 . \text{(left distributive law)}$$
> Here $\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{1}$ denote the $2 × 2$ zero and identity matrices, which are also quaternions.

So far so good.. but then he mentioned:

> The right distributive law
> $$(q_2 + q_3 )q_1 = q_2 q_1 + q_3 q_1$$ of course
> holds too, and is distinct from the left distributive
> law because of the non-commutative product.

I'm lost here -- why the right distributive law *of course* holds?
Is it that in ring's definition, if the addition is commutative, then we only need the left distribution law on product operation?

Comment: It "of course holds" because it is true. The point Stillwell is making is that you cannot deduce right distributivity from left distributivity because multiplication is not commutative; so the two distributivity laws have to be stated separately and checked separately. It "of course holds" because it holds in matrices, which is how he has defined the quaternions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, so the fact it holds comes from the definition via matrix. But, in general, would it be possible for a ring with commutative addition, and product operation that left distribution law holds, does not hold right distribution law?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible, but it wouldn't be a *ring*, now would it? If you don't require addition to be commutative, they are called "near rings". An example of a structure with two operations, a commutative "addition" and a product that left distributes but does not right distribute is given by [ordinal arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784757/742); you may object that the additive structure is only a monoid and not a group, though. An near ring with commutative addition is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/513244/742).